# In Angular 6 set div value from other div values

Tags: angular

I want to set a div value according to another div value:

```
<div #priceRef>{{ price(9) }}</div>
<div>{{ priceRef }}</div>
```

A more complex example, I want to calculate the difference of 2 div values:

```
<div #total1Ref>{{ total(1) }}</div>
<div #total2Ref>{{ total(2) }}</div>
<div>{{ total1Ref - total2Ref }}</div>
```

The idea here is to avoid extra calls to `price` and `total` to save time.

Comment: Compute those totals once and for all in your component, and save the result in fields. That way, you won't need to compile again and again. Note that the difference computation is only one of the things that causes a recomputation of the total. Unless your component uses the OnPush strategy, every change detection causes the totals to be recomputed.

Comment: Not related but you should avoir binding functions to your template for performance reasons.

Comment: If those functions are pure, a cleaner/better approach would be to use a pipes

Comment: @JBNizet I can't compute the total once for all because the total is a sum of elements and the UI allows to add/remove elements. So for each modification I need to recompute the total. But I would like to do it once per modification and reuse this total.

Comment: That's exactly what you should do. Recompute them when they need to be recomputed. Just do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can access to text via `innerText` property, this will work only if in your text will be only numbers

```
<div #total1Ref>{{ total(1) }}</div>
<div #total2Ref>{{ total(2) }}</div>
<div>{{ total1Ref.innerText - total2Ref.innerText }}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you use something with the value attribute, option for example, you can leverage the value attribute and accomplish what you are looking for.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<option #total1Ref value={{value1}}>{{value1}}</option>
            <option #total2Ref value={{value2}}>{{value2}}</option>
            <div>{{ total1Ref.value - total2Ref.value }}</div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  value1 = 10;
  value2 = 5;   
}
```

**Revision:**

Below is example of using a function

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<input #total1Ref value={{total(20)}} style="border: 0;"/>
            <input #total2Ref value={{total(10)}} style="border: 0;"/>
            <div>{{ total1Ref.value - total2Ref.value }}</div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  value1 = 10;
  value2 = 5;  

  total(num){
    return this.value1 + this.value2 + num
  } 
}
```

Comment: How to do it with functions and call it once?

Comment: Please see updated revision, using a borderless input would be one option to call the function only once.

Comment: thanks for the revision, it seems to work with input but I use div and it doesn't work with div, that's why I put it in my question title.

Comment: Understand, you will need to explore other answers if using something other than a div us not an option.